# Oracle Materialized View refresh error or success

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized

We have a Materialized view that is created for remote database view (db link). The mt view is refreshed (Complete) every night. We have a requirement to provide a client with daily email status of the refresh whether the refresh is successful or not (for any reason). Currently the refresh is happening through DBMS_JOB. How can the system check automatically the status of the refresh and act upon it?  If I create a procedure that calls DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH (my mt view,'C') will it fail if the call to refresh is not successful (e.g. network issues)? Am I able to catch it in EXCEPTION and log the error? Also, is DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG useful in refreshing MT view?

Thank you

Comment: Of course you can catch the exception in PL/SQL and act upon it. But the code of your PL/SQL procedure and the error you get when the DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH call fails would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You really should be using dbms_scheduler instead of dbms_job anyways since dbms_job has been deprecated as of 10g (provided you are on at least 10g... if not, you may want to consider upgrading).

While you can use dbms_scheduler to schedule mview refreshes, mviews have that capability already built in.  The below command will schedule the mview to refresh (complete) every day at 1AM:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW <mviewname>
 REFRESH COMPLETE
 NEXT (TRUNC (SYSDATE+1) + 1/24);
```

The syntax for the interval can be a little tricky until you get used to it... I would start with the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2001.htm#CCHECCJB).

To check on when the mview was last refreshed:

```
select owner, mview_name, last_refresh_date  from dba_mviews;
```

Therefore, if you are refreshing the mview every morning, you can set up a scheduler job to send an email if the mview was or was not refreshed that morning (based on the results of the above query).

Comment: So, USER_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES or ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES always has the record of last refresh if that refresh is successful, correct? What happens if that refresh is not successful? Would the query return the record for last day refresh or no record at all? Also, how do I capture the error why the refresh failed?

Comment: @JKint I don't use *_mview_refresh_times.  I just use *_mviews, which always has a record regardless if the refresh failed or not (just last_refresh_date will be your indication whether the mview is stale).  As for how to capture the error, I see that sys.snap$ stores the error# (which, I "assume" is the ORA-# of the last refresh, though I haven't tested this), but I don't see an equivalent column in any of the *_mview or *_refresh views)  However, even if this is true, your DBA may or may not what to grant select on sys.snap$ to the application user...

Comment: Thanks, will check that.  Wouldn't calling DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH in a procedure raise an error if refresh is not successful? The client is much more concerned in unsuccessful refresh than in successful one (which I can check in all_mviews. The bigger priority is letting client know that refresh didn't happen and the reason why .

Comment: @JKint Yes, calling dbms_mview_refresh in a procedure will certainly raise an error if it isn't successful (that you can then trap and handle the exception accordingly via sending an email or whatever).  Said procedure can then be scheduled via dbms_scheduler.  I find it odd that I don't see a way to trap the error on automatic refresh through one of the all_ views (instead of needing to go to sys.snap$ directly), but I digress.... Could be there somewhere, but brain is already on the weekend...